# SpringBoot: Where to put internal container classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-structure

I have the following project structure:

```
app
|
|--> config
|--> controller
|--> dto
|--> exception
|--> model
|--> repository
|--> service
|--> utils
```

'model' is used for the POJO's. Every database table has a own class with Entity annotation.
'dto' is used for the transformation of the POJO's into the response objects by the help of a ModelMapper. Not every POJO has a own DTO, because for some basic entites there must not be a transformation.

Now I have some other classes, which acts like POJO's, but won't be used for database interaction. I need them for some temporary calculation and sort orders, but in the end the attributes of those objects will be saved in a DTO.

Where should I put such classes? In my opinion they shouldn't be in 'model', because they aren't POJO's, nor in 'dto', because they won't be streamed to the customer. 
Should I create a new folder (how to name it?! internaltype?)?

Comment: I had a similar use case once, so we had put those 'temporary classes' in utils folder as they are  kind of extra 'hands' for the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, We can move all the `Class` which are used for Database to `entites` package and put `Internal` Classes in `models` package,

```
app
|
|--> config
|--> controller
|--> dto
|--> exception
|--> models
|--> entities
|--> repository
|--> service
|--> utils
```

Another I would suggest like below. I feel the below is kind of neat when you look.

```
app
|
|--> config
|--> controller
|--> models
     |--> dto //This holds the DTO classes
     |--> entities (or) dao //This holds the Database classes
     |--> Pojo_1.java
     |--> Pojo_2.java
|--> exception
|--> repository
|--> service
|--> utils
```